# use singleton logic within a classmethod

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently using this piece of code :

```py
class FileSystem(metaclass=Singleton):
    """File System manager based on Spark"""

    def __init__(self, spark):
        self._path = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
        self._fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(
            spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
        )

    @classmethod
    def without_spark(cls):
        with Spark() as spark:
            return cls(spark)
```

My object depends obviously on the Spark object (another object that I created - If you need to see its code, I can add it but I do not think it is required for my current issue).

It can be used in 2 differents ways resulting the same behavior :

```py
fs = FileSystem.without_spark()

# OR

with Spark() as spark:
    fs = FileSystem(spark)
```

My problem is that, even if `FileSystem` is a singleton, using the class method `without_spark` makes me enter (`__enter__`) the context manager of spark, which lead to a connection to spark cluster, which takes a lot of time. How can I make that the first execution of `without_spark` do the connection, but the next one only returns the already created instance?

The expected behavior would be something like this :

```py
    @classmethod
    def without_spark(cls):
        if not cls.exists:  # I do not know how to persist this information in the class
            with Spark() as spark:
                return cls(spark)
        else:
            return cls()
```

Comment: It seems that your context manager is not really needed as you will leave the context with the return statement and all subsequent usage of the returned `FileSystem` instance happens outside of the context.

Comment: @user2390182 I know the behavior is a bit strange. But actually, I need spark to be connected when I define my FileSystem. And once disconnected, FileSystem keeps working. They use java objects behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like

```
import contextlib

class FileSystem(metaclass=Singleton):
    """File System manager based on Spark"""

    spark = None


    def __init__(self, spark):
        self._path = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
        self._fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(
            spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
        )

    @classmethod
    def without_spark(cls):
        if cls.spark is None:
            cm = cls.spark = Spark()
        else:
            cm = contextlib.nullcontext(cls.spark)
            
        with cm as s:
            return cls(s)
```

The first time `without_spark` is called, a new instance of `Spark` is created and used as a context manager. Subsequent calls reuse the same `Spark` instance and use a null context manager.

---

I believe your approach will work as well; you just need to initialize `exists` to be `False`, then set it to `True` the first (and every, really) time you call the class method.

```
class FileSystem(metaclass=Singleton):
    """File System manager based on Spark"""

    exists = False

    def __init__(self, spark):
        self._path = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
        self._fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(
            spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
        )

    @classmethod
    def without_spark(cls):
        if not cls.exists:
            cls.exists = True
            with Spark() as spark:
                return cls(spark)
        else:
            return cls()
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the context manager when the context is closed with the return statement and all subsequent usages of `cls.spark` are "out of context"?

Comment: I fixed the name error. I'm almost certainly still botching the intended semantics. (I'm answering this from a strictly formal standpoint, which could be completely wrong.) It's not clear to me what the semantics of the context manager are; the OP's example suggests that `fs` can be used outside the context manager, but maybe that's not the case.

Comment: @chepner yes, `fs` can be used outside the context manager. It just need to be inside the context manager when `__init__`. But your anwser does not work; It still makes me go through `with spark` each time I call the class method. I want to do the `with` only once, the first time i use the methode. I made an edit on my post, added a piece of what I would like (but I'm not sure it is easy to understand)

Comment: OK, I've updated the answer to use a null context manager on subsequent calls to `without_spark`, though I think your approach will work as well: you just need to initialize `exists = False` when the class is defined, then set `cls.exists = True` when it is first seen to be false.

Comment: Haaaa ... I tried to do this, but actually, I added the statement `self.exists = True` in `__init__` which was not working because it was only changing the value for the object, not for the class. Stupid mistake. But thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Can't you make the constructor argument optional, and initiate the `Spark` lazily, e.g. in a `property` (or `functools.cached_property`):

```
from functools import cached_property

class FileSystem(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self, spark=None):
        self._spark = spark

    @cached_property
    def spark(self):
        if self._spark:
            return self._spark
        return self._spark := Spark()

    @cached_property
    def path(self):
        return self.spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

    @cached_property
    def fs(self):
        with self.spark:
            return self.spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(
                self.spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()
            )
```

Comment: I've never seen `cached_property`. Need to study a bit to understand.

Comment: It's just like a normal property, but only evaluated on the first call, then cached.